# Application "blinks" when speechRecognition is restarted

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application that among other things , lets user interact with it by voice recognition (Speech to Text).For example user speaks the word "contacts" and the application can recognize and proceed to use logic to it to do something (i.e get the list of contacts and present them).
Now I have used a custom speech Recognizer , and not the one Google provides with the alert dialog.
I also have an animated gradient as a background with some colors.
From the RecognitionListener we get either an error as a response or we get results from the method onResults(Bundle results).In both cases after the response i need to restart the listener in order for the user to continue to interact with the application. However, when my speechRecognition is destroyed and created again, my application "blinks"(very quick black screen, but then the Ui is returned to normal).
I know that the problem is happening because i try to destroy my speechListener and then i re-create it(By calling the function restartSpeechListener), but i cannot seem to find a way to solve this "blinking".
Below is my code for the speechRecognizer initiation and restart :

```
public void startRecognising() {
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mySpeechRecogniser listener = new mySpeechRecogniser();
    Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            "el");
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(listener);
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
    startActivity(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
}

// Restart speech recogniser
public void restartSpeechListener() {
    mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
    mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    startRecognising();
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be very  helpful !

Comment: Do you know that the blinking is happening inside the `restartSpeechListener` method? Does this happen in the main thread? You could debug using a breakpoint to see exactly when the blink happens.

Comment: Hello , and thank you for you comment ! I did use debug and breakpoints , and the problem seems to occur right after the command startActivity(mSpeechRecognizerIntent).My guess is that this command makes a new intent pop, and this is why the blinking happens. As far as your question, yes I am running the speechRecognizer in the main Thread.

Comment: So probably the black thing popping up is due to the intent. An activity that is not transparent shows up for a short time. You said it is a custom speech recognizer. Is it made by you? Do you know if the target Intent is an activity? And can you customize its theme?

Comment: Sorry , poor choice of words by me. When I said I used a custom speech recognizer i meant that i did not use google's speech recognizer with the alert dialog , but i did use the SpeechRecognizer interface and gave it a RecognitionListener. Anyways , after seeing your comment , i went back and tried removing the line startActivity(mSpeechRecognizer) , and the blinking no longer happens. I thought this command was mandatory for the listener to start listening, however the app seems to be working properly.

Comment: You can add this as an answer to your question and mark it as right, then. :) Keep rocking